# Find the distinct with different string values from SQL select

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, distinct

I want to remove the duplicate rows Using Select Query how can I get rid of the duplicate rows.

The following out put produces redundant records, How to get the distinct results?

```
SELECT E.EMAIL_ID, T.FIRST_NAME, T.LAST_NAME, CY.COUNTRY_ID 
FROM PLAYER P
INNER JOIN PLAYERTYPE T ON P.PLAYER_ID = T.PLAYER_ID
INNER JOIN PLAYER_CONTACT C ON T.PLAYER_ID = C.PLAYER_ID 
INNER JOIN CONTACT_EMAIL E ON E.CONTACT_ID = C.CONTACT_ID
INNER JOIN COUNTRY_TABLE CY ON P.COUNTRY_ID = CY.COUNTRY_ID
WHERE CY.COUNTRY_CODE='AUS'
AND T.PLAYER_TYPE IN ('NEW', 'EXE')
```

Current Output:

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | EMAIL_ID | COUNTRY_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MARK | CLARKSON | dfgh@gmail.com | 04 |
| MARK | CLARKSON | DFGH@GMAIL.com | 04 |
| CATH | SPEARS | tygh@yahoo.com | 04 |
| FESS | LOPEZ | fgvhb@yandex.com | 04 |
| FEXS | LOPEZ | byvg@google.com | 04 |
| FEXS | LOPEZ | BYVG@GOOGLE.COM | 04 |
| EOVA | SMITH | ghjkjh@sdf.com | 04 |

Expected Output:

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | EMAIL_ID | COUNTRY_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MARK | CLARKSON | dfgh@gmail.com | 04 |
| CATH | SPEARS | tygh@yahoo.com | 04 |
| FESS | LOPEZ | fgvhb@yandex.com | 04 |
| FEXS | LOPEZ | BYVG@GOOGLE.COM | 04 |
| EOVA | SMITH | ghjkjh@sdf.com | 04 |

Tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.EMAIL_ID, T.FIRST_NAME, T.LAST_NAME, CY.COUNTRY_ID 
FROM PLAYER P
INNER JOIN PLAYERTYPE T ON P.PLAYER_ID = T.PLAYER_ID
INNER JOIN PLAYER_CONTACT C ON T.PLAYER_ID = C.PLAYER_ID 
INNER JOIN CONTACT_EMAIL E ON E.CONTACT_ID = C.CONTACT_ID
INNER JOIN COUNTRY_TABLE CY ON P.COUNTRY_ID = CY.COUNTRY_ID
WHERE CY.COUNTRY_CODE='AUS'
 AND T.PLAYER_TYPE IN ('NEW', 'EXE')
```

---

```
SELECT T.FIRST_NAME, T.LAST_NAME, E.EMAIL_ID, CY.COUNTRY_ID 
FROM PLAYER P
INNER JOIN PLAYERTYPE T ON P.PLAYER_ID = T.PLAYER_ID
INNER JOIN PLAYER_CONTACT C ON T.PLAYER_ID = C.PLAYER_ID 
INNER JOIN CONTACT_EMAIL E ON E.CONTACT_ID = C.CONTACT_ID
INNER JOIN COUNTRY_TABLE CY ON P.COUNTRY_ID = CY.COUNTRY_ID
WHERE CY.COUNTRY_CODE='AUS'
AND T.PLAYER_TYPE IN ('NEW', 'EXE')
GROUP BY T.FIRST_NAME, T.LAST_NAME, E.EMAIL_ID, CY.COUNTRY_ID
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/z6lxa6g2).

Comment: You have to decide (and describe) which row you want if there are two (or more) for a player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `DISTINCT` + [`LOWER`](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-string-functions/oracle-lower/):

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.FIRST_NAME, 
                T.LAST_NAME, 
                LOWER(E.EMAIL_ID) AS EMAIL_ID, 
                CY.COUNTRY_ID 
FROM PLAYER P
INNER JOIN PLAYERTYPE T ON P.PLAYER_ID = T.PLAYER_ID
INNER JOIN PLAYER_CONTACT C ON T.PLAYER_ID = C.PLAYER_ID 
INNER JOIN CONTACT_EMAIL E ON E.CONTACT_ID = C.CONTACT_ID
INNER JOIN COUNTRY_TABLE CY ON P.COUNTRY_ID = CY.COUNTRY_ID
WHERE CY.COUNTRY_CODE='AUS' AND T.PLAYER_TYPE IN ('NEW', 'EXE')
```

Output:

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | EMAIL_ID | COUNTRY_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MARK | CLARKSON | dfgh@gmail.com | 04 |
| CATH | SPEARS | tygh@yahoo.com | 04 |
| FESS | LOPEZ | fgvhb@yandex.com | 04 |
| FEXS | LOPEZ | byvg@google.com | 04 |
| EOVA | SMITH | ghjkjh@sdf.com | 04 |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/CkFIUv8b).

Answer (score 0):

The repeated errors seem to have different email addresses, or the same email address with different cases.  Try removing the email column or simply applying a Lowercase() to the email (or whatever the equivalent is for it in your db engine)

Answer (score 0):

Using DISTINCT will only mask the problem. It might give you results you like, but it will hide a gremlin that will cause a problem down the road, particularly for performance if you end up dealing in massive data volumes.

I'm guessing that `PLAYER_CONTACT` has multiple rows per `PLAYER_ID`. If so, joining a single row from `PLAYER` to `PLAYER_CONTACT` will result in multiple output rows. I'm also guessing that `CONTACT_EMAIL` can contain multiple rows per contact. if so, joining to that will multiply your output by the # of rows per contact.  So if you have 5 contacts per player, and 5 emails per contact, joining both of these one-to-many tables **will result in 25 output rows**.  That is what causes all the other columns to show duplicate values. Now imagine that it's 1:10000 and 1:10000... a single player would return 100,000,000 rows. You can then hide that with DISTINCT but you'll use a lot of temp space and time writing/reading to temp to do that sort, and only hide the fact that there's fundamental probablem in your query granularity.

So it's a matter of changing your query approach. Do you really want all possible contacts and all possible emails for those contacts? Or do you want one row per player? If one row per player, you will either have to decide which contact and which email you want to return, or you will need to return some kind of LISTAGG string to show them all in a single row.